# Exception Unhandled System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.'

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ms-access

Good day to everyone here... Please I've been trying to write this code to update my data in a database I've created in Access through Vb.Net. I want it in a way that after I have saved a data and want to correct or make an update to it, then it will be possible...

The Data types for all the fields are **Number**

Just that aside **MealID** the other two fields, I've changed the field size of those fields in Access to **Double** where*MealID** is **Long Integer**

Please I'll be very grateful to any help I can get.. Thank you...

```
conn.Open()
     cmd = conn.CreateCommand()
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
     cmd.CommandText = "update tblsales 
     set MealID = '" + txtID.Text + "' 
       where Waakye ='" + txtwaakye.Text +
       "' and Salad = '" + txtsalad.Text +  "'"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd.Close()
```

Comment: `MealID` is not a string Type, but you're passing it as a string. -- You need to use Parameters to build a query. It's mandatory. The fact that you're somewhat *allowed* to use string concatenation is not an excuse. -- *a database I've created in Access*: what is the `mysql` tag for?

Comment: Please can re write my code using that for me, I don't you know how to use that... Thank you...

Comment: [OleDbParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter) Class. -- Note that the Connection and Command objects must be declared in-place with `Using` statements. **Do not** store the Connection. Especially with an Access db. See the linked documentation.

Comment: Apostrophe delimiters are used only for text type field. Remove them. For using parameters, review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i

Comment: Thank you... Now I am able to run the code using the parameters but I don't see the changes or the update in the database...